# Accessing MVC ViewData in webforms Site.Master in mixed architecture solution

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

We are working on an ASP MVC3 project, which has legacy ASPX webforms in it. So our solution is based on mixed architecture suggested here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingRazorViewsAndWebFormsMasterPagesWithASPNETMVC3.aspx

We are using Site.Master webforms as the Master page for both webforms and MVC pages.

Now we need to pass ViewData from MVC view to Site.Master.

As ViewData cannot be directly used in webforms, can anyone please suggest how to make it to work.

Thanks

Comment: as much as i hate the idea, you're looking at session here